# go-ethereum licensing under proprietary software

Tags: go-ethereum

Hello Ethereum Community,

The company I work for is developing a Ethereum-related software
that uses go-ethereum for a wide range of cases. However,
software itself will be closed source (proprietary), which leads me
to my question, how should I proceed using go-ethereum in that project
without violating LGPLv3?

Browsing over a similar [issue](https://github.com/harmony-one/harmony/issues/3600)
a possible approach is to move go-ethereum to a dedicated repository and load it
as a plugin. I am wondering if it is legal to clone go-ethereum project making it
publicly available on my company's github under LGPLv3 and importing this newly created package on the application that has a more restrictive license.

IANAL nor do I expected IANAL-like expertise, I'd just like some guidance on this topic as all these license compatibility themes has lots of intricacies.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about licenses are out of scope for this site. If you want to avoid problems hire a lawyer. The best advice I can give is that mixing proprietary license and open sources license like GPL, LGPL is problematic.